# how to use whenever gem to send emails periodically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have following condition in controller to trigger the email notification

controller.rb

```
 if !@data[:done]
   UserNotifier.send_email.deliver
 end
```

I want to send emails weekly so i am following the article below

https://gianthatworks.com/entry/using-the-whenever-gem-in-your-rails-app

I am at the step to add task in schedule.rb but if i do

```
every :sunday do
  UserNotifier.send_email.deliver
end
```

and run whenever in terminal then i get error

`uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Whenever::JobList:0x007fb7fa1193d8>>::UserNotifier (NameError)`

Any idea how do i update schedule.rb so i can send email only on sunday?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i was missing was this.

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
```